# Object undefined in objectoutputstream

Tags: java

I am developing server-client side java program, where I have sliced an jpg image using getSubimage() and saved into int image[][][]
The class below initialises connection with the server and receives an array, however compiler states that readObject() is undifined. Any suggestions how to fix this problem?
Thanks!

```
public void con() throws IOException {

        int port = 7676;

        ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
        Socket socket = null;

        // try to establish the connection to the server
        try {
            socket = new Socket(hostName, port);

            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

            int pixels[][][] = new int[20][20][400];
            pixels = (int[][][])is.readObject();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it must be of type ObjectInputStream, so you should write something like this:

```
pixels = (int[][][])inputStream.readObject();
```

where inputStream is type of ObjectInputStream.

Comment: Yes, hook the socket.getInputStream up to an ObjectInputStream. Do not use a Reader (that is for text data, won't work with binary streams).